# Why is it every time my tableview reloads, there are duplicates in it?

Tags: swift, firebase, uitableview, google-cloud-firestore

So I made a "like" button in my tableview cell. Every time it's tapped, it updates the value of the number of likes for a certain post. The problem is that when it updates and `snapshotListener` takes effect, it adds another copy of the data so I'll have duplicates. For example, I have one post with 100 likes; when the "like" button is tapped, I'll have 2 of the same post - one with 100 likes and the other one with 101 likes.

```
import UIKit
import Firebase



class motivationviewcontroller : UIViewController,UITableViewDataSource ,UITableViewDelegate{


var motivationThoughts = [motivationDailyModel]()
var Mous = motivationDailyModel()
var tableview : UITableView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    print("madicc")
    
    print("the user logged in is \( String(describing: Auth.auth().currentUser?.email))")
        
    tableview =  UITableView(frame: view.bounds, style: .plain)
           tableview.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
           view.addSubview(tableview)
    
    
    var layoutGuide : UILayoutGuide!
    layoutGuide = view.safeAreaLayoutGuide
    
    let cellNib = UINib(nibName: "dailyMotivationTableViewCell", bundle: nil)
    tableview.register(cellNib, forCellReuseIdentifier: "DailyThoughtCELL")
    tableview.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: layoutGuide.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
    tableview.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: layoutGuide.topAnchor).isActive = true
    tableview.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: layoutGuide.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
    tableview.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: layoutGuide.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
    
    
    tableview.dataSource = self
    tableview.delegate = self
    
    
    loaddailymotivation()
    self.tableview.reloadData()
    
     
}

override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
  //loaddailymotivation()
    self.tableview.reloadData()
    
}




func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    motivationThoughts.count
   }
 
   func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "DailyThoughtCELL", for: indexPath) as? dailyMotivationTableViewCell
  
        cell!.generateCellsforDailymotivation(_MotivationdataMODEL: self.motivationThoughts[indexPath.row])
        return cell!
   }
      
      
          func loaddailymotivation() {
    
    FirebaseReferece(.MotivationDAILY).addSnapshotListener { (snapshot, error) in
    
        if (error != nil) {
            print(error!.localizedDescription)
        } else{
            
            guard let snapshot = snapshot else {return}
            
            for allDocuments in snapshot.documents {
                
                let data = allDocuments.data()
               
                let dailyMotivationID =  data ["objectID"] as! String
               
                let dailymotivationTitle = data["Motivation title"] as! String //calls the data thats heald inside of motivation title in firebase
                
                let dailyMotivationScripture = data["daily motivation scripture"] as! String //calls the data thats heald inside of Motivation script in firebase
               
                let dailyMotivationNumberOfLikes = data["Number of likes in daily motivation post"]as! Int
                
                let MdataModel = motivationDailyModel(RealMotivationID: dailyMotivationID, RealmotivationTitle: dailymotivationTitle, RealmotivationScrip: dailyMotivationScripture, RealmotivationNumberOfLikes: dailyMotivationNumberOfLikes)
              
                self.motivationThoughts.append(MdataModel)
                self.tableview.reloadData()
                
          }
        }
        
     }
   }
```

Comment: You don't need to call reload every time you append an object. You can move your reload call out of your documents loop

Comment: if I don't call it there it refuses to load and shows me empty cells

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are correctly loading data from Firebase.

However, before `self.motivationThoughts.append(MdataModel)`, you need to clear the previous data, otherwise it would just append the fresh data to what you had previously, which I believe explains what you are seeing.

Something like `self.motivationThoughts.removeAll()` will do it.

Answer (score 2):

Can you try to remove all item in your array before append it

```
self.motivationThoughts.removeAll() 
self.motivationThoughts.append(MdataModel)
self.tableview.reloadData()
```